# getSession() returning null on API route (Next Auth)

Tags: api, authentication, next.js

getSession({req}) returns null, im using next auth. Im trying to use it in one of the api routes.
I've been searching a lot but nothing works ;(

Im expecting to get the session to check that there's an user to follow next instructions.

Comment: versions? Some of the code you are using? What session management? Next-Auth?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.